# How to double string stored at an even index and triple string stored at an index that is multiple of 3

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

[image]Below is the scenario.

Write a function called multiply_strings. Multiply strings should have one parameter, a list of strings.
It should return a modified list according to the following changes:

- Every string stored at an even index should be doubled.
- Every string stored at an index that is a multiple of 3 should be tripled.
- Every other string should remain unchanged.

These changes should "stack"

**test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]**

If your function works correctly, this will originally print:
['AAAAAA', 'B', 'CC', 'DDD', 'EE', 'F', 'GGGGGG']

```
def multiply_strings(test_list): 
    for i in test_list:
        print(i) 

test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"] print(multiply_strings(test_list))
```

Comment: You have tagged this question with python, but you haven’t included any code.

Comment: def multiply_strings(test_list):
    for i in test_list:
        print(i,end='')



test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
print(multiply_strings(test_list))

Comment: I am actually stuck at execution part. I am iterating over items in the list but dont know how to double and triple.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Your code simply *prints* each element the specified number of times. (Without further decorations, each `print` statement will also add a newline.) Then when you call the function, you also `print` the return value from the function. (It doesn't explicitly `return` anything at all, so it will implicitly `return None`.) You want to figure out something more useful to do rather than `print` the values. Your assignment says your function should modify a list.

Comment: `>>> "A" * 2 => 'AA'` and `>>> "A" * 2 * 3 => 'AAAAAA'`. Also look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). You should have all you need to do a for loop, a modulo (`%`) and produce your result I think...

Comment: One solution to your problem could be `[v * (2 if i%2==0 else 1) * (3 if i%3==0 else 1) for i,v in enumerate(s) ]` but I would not submit that if it is an assignment... better study it and expand it into a for loop ;)

Comment: Thank you Urban and Tripleee. I am actually new to python and learning it for fun and May be later my field later on. I haven’t reached to enumerate yet but will read about it. This one has been giving me a tough time and I thought to check here for guidance. I am committed to learning python and I am hopeful I will take learning from your comments and try to crack this assignment. 

Thank you once again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments already covered it but I thought I would try to put an easier to understand answer down here.

```
def multiply_strings(test_list):
    for i, _ in enumerate(test_list):

        # 2 if statements are required for changes to stack
        if not i % 2:  # even
            test_list[i] *= 2

        if not i % 3:  # multiple of 3
            test_list[i] *= 3

    return test_list


test_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

print(multiply_strings(test_list))
```

*= is the same idea as +=, it just takes the item itself and multiplies by the number on the right.

Note that instead of enumerate, you could technically just use `for i in range(len(test_list))`.

Comment: Thank you Rolv Apneseth :) Really appreciate your support.